# "Freeze" bitbake workspace while working with it

Tags: openembedded, bitbake

How do I **"freeze" workspace state** to **disable update** and rebuild of components that I'm not working with?
It gets really annoying, when some components from our local layer, update and start to rebuild, which can be very long task.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can always build only the package you working on. Bitbake also allows you to define here every step you want to do (which is helpful when you just modify one part for testing):
`bitbake -c compile <packagename>` to stop after the compile step or just plain `bitbake <packagename>` for everything. I ran into cases where I wanted to run a `bitbake -c clean <package> && bitbake -c package <packagename>` but most times `bitbake <packagename>` should be sufficient.
You can also run against a single recipe version: `bitbake -b recipe_1.2.bb`.

I am not sure if you can build an entire image without checking for updates.

Comment: however, I am working on task to reduce image size, and trying to skip do_fetch step of dependent components(actually any component), to build the whole image and check if the size has changed. 
bitbaking it will initiate do_fetch tasks thus this solution won't work in this case.

Comment: I would try the offline mode then. With the offline mode it will take the files that are on the file system only and will not check remote sources. You can download the files before you start to build. See http://www.crashcourse.ca/wiki/index.php/Yocto_Project_Quick_Start#Taking_advantage_of_earlier_downloaded_tarballs_.5BOPTIONAL.5D for more details

Answer (score 0):

In newer bitbake versions than the one I was using when asking a question, there is such a possibility:
BB_SRCREV_POLICY = "cache"